# Move Scene in corona

Tags: coronasdk, scene

I am new to corona and my Problem id I have a long scene and in that I have a ball body. When it moves up i want to move the scene up. How to do this in Corona.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is done using a display group to contain your entire scene (the level, the ball, everything) and then move that display group. Physics in Corona don't work between display groups for this very reason, so that that you can move the scene without affecting physics inside the scene. Refer to the "Egg Breaker" sample project.