# How can i make a slider for levels like in Angry Birds in Corona?

Tags: drag, slide, coronasdk, scene, levels

How can i make a slider for levels like in Angry Birds in Corona or like Samsung Galaxy S2 mainpage? When i drag the scene, it brings the other parts of the scene. How can i do that in Corona? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might be of use to you: https://stackoverflow.com/a/7229683/1369488

You could make a display group, longer than the screen, that has all of your level icons. Use the "moved" touch event to sense when the user drags, and have the display group move according to the position of the touch.